# How do you batch process drawing in imagemagick 7?

Tags: bash, image-processing, imagemagick, mogrify

I have made a command that works with magick 7. It uses the new `%[fx]` and draw syntax

```
magick input.png \
 -stroke black -strokewidth 3 \
  -draw "line 0,0 20,0" \
  -draw "line 0,0 0,20" \
  -draw "line 0,%[fx:h] 20,%[fx:h]" \
  -draw "line 0,%[fx:h] 0,%[fx:h-20]" \
  -draw "line %[fx:w],0 %[fx:w-20],0" \
  -draw "line %[fx:w],0 %[fx:w],20" \
  -draw "line %[fx:w],%[fx:h] %[fx:w-20],%[fx:h]" \
  -draw "line %[fx:w],%[fx:h] %[fx:w],%[fx:h-20]" \
output.png
```

Unfortunately it does not work for batch processing with `magick mogrify`

```
magick mogrify -stroke black -strokewidth 3 \
  -draw "line 0,0 20,0" \
  -draw "line 0,0 0,20" \
  -draw "line 0,%[fx:h] 20,%[fx:h]" \
  -draw "line 0,%[fx:h] 0,%[fx:h-20]" \
  -draw "line %[fx:w],0 %[fx:w-20],0" \
  -draw "line %[fx:w],0 %[fx:w],20" \
  -draw "line %[fx:w],%[fx:h] %[fx:w-20],%[fx:h]" \
  -draw "line %[fx:w],%[fx:h] %[fx:w],%[fx:h-20]" \
-- *.png
```

and gives an error

```
mogrify: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `%' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4059.
```

I could use the v6 syntax but this does not seem like it should be necessary.

Comment: Mogrify is old IM 6 and is called by Imagemagick 7.  Only IM 7 magick (replacement for convert) understands %[fx:...] inline commands.  So you will have process using a FOR loop with magick. You will not be able to do that with IM 7 magick mogrify.

Comment: I would also point out that %[fx:w] and %[fx:h] are off the image by one pixel. The last column is at w-1 and the last row is at h-1. IM will draw to these positions but you may not see anything depending upon how thick your lines are.

Comment: @fmw42 That's unfortunate... And odd their is no way to batch process since I thought that was the main point of image magick.
edit: Yea I noticed it being off after posting this. Thank you though.

Comment: The issue is that mogrify is old IM 6 structure and is just called when using IM 7 magick mogrify. It did not have all the upgrades put in to IM 7 magick.  One of the big things in magick is the ability to do fx computations inline. But it was not put into mogrify.  You can create a number of variables for each fx: in separate commands and use the variables in your magick mogrify command to do the draw.

Comment: I will just loop it. If you want to copy that into an answer I can accept it. @fmw42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that mogrify in Imagemagick is old IM 6 structure and is just called when using IM 7 magick mogrify. It did not have all the upgrades put in to IM 7 magick. One of the big things in IM 7 magick is the ability to do fx computations inline. But it was not put into mogrify. You can create a number of variables for each fx: in separate commands and use the variables in your magick mogrify command to do the draw.

In Unix syntax, this would be:

```
infile="input.png"
declare `magick "$infile" -format "ww=%w\n hh=%h\n www=%[fx:w-20]\n hhh=%[fx:h-20]\n" info:`
magick "$infile" -stroke black -strokewidth 3 \
  -draw "line 0,0 20,0" \
  -draw "line 0,0 0,20" \
  -draw "line 0,${hh} 20,${hh}" \
  -draw "line 0,${hh} 0,${hhh}" \
  -draw "line ${ww},0 ${www},0" \
  -draw "line ${ww},0 ${ww},20" \
  -draw "line ${ww},${hh} ${hhh},${hh}" \
  -draw "line ${ww},${hh} ${ww},${hhh}" \
output.png
```